# Get-InboxRule but only show the ones where ForwardTo or ForwardAsAttachmentTo aren't empty

Tags: powershell, foreach, outlook, where-clause, rules

I have to check all our users Inbox rules. I managed to get all the inbox rules written to a text file. But i only need the ones where they forward it to an other mail.

What i have so far:

```
$mails = get-content D:\test.txt


$test = ForEach ($mail in $mails){


  $m = Get-InboxRule -Mailbox $mail | measure
  $mail
  $m.Count

}

$test| Out-File -FilePath "D:\testresult.txt" -Append
```

In the Test.txt i have all the Mail-addresses:

```
john.doe@test.com 
john.deer@test.com
johnny.dude@test.com
etc etc.
```

How can can i add the check "where Forwardto -ne $null"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add it to your `Get-InboxRule` command so

```
Get-InboxRule -Mailbox $mail | measure
```

becomes

```
Get-InboxRule -Mailbox $mail | Where-Object {$_.ForwardTo -ne $Null} | measure
```